# Nested aggregation in mongodb and sort on field

Tags: mongodb

I have created a mongo query for nested aggregation of the following dataset

ie

```
[{
bank: 'wells fargo',
time: '21/05/2019 02:01 AM',
amount: 1000
},
{
bank: 'bank of america',
time: '16/06/2019 02:46 AM',
amount: 4840
}]
```

I needed to created a mongoquery for the nested aggregation ie **for every bank for every time find the sum**

I created the following query

```
    db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        $group: 
            {
                _id: 
                    {
                        'bank': '$bank', 
                        'time': '$time'
                    }, 
                sum: 
                    {
                        $sum: '$amount'
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        $group: 
            {
                _id: '$_id.bank', 
                data: {'$push': '$$ROOT'}, 
                sum: {$sum: '$sum'}
            }
    } 
]).pretty()
```

Which gave the result as

```
{"_id" : "wells fargo",
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "bank" : "wells fargo",
                "time" : "21/05/2019 02:01 AM"
            },
            "sum" : 1000
        }]}
```

and it works fine but the issue here is that i need to **sort the result by time** so I added sort in the end like

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        $group: 
            {
                _id: 
                    {
                        'bank': '$bank', 
                        'time': '$time'
                    }, 
                sum: 
                    {
                        $sum: '$amount'
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        $group: 
            {
                _id: '$_id.bank', 
                data: {'$push': '$$ROOT'}, 
                sum: {$sum: '$sum'}
            }
    }, {$sort: {time:-1}} 
]).pretty()
```

but this doesnt seem to work. What wrong is in sorting method implemented?

Answer (score 0):

when you are grouping, you are neglecting the time property that's why when sort your data by time it won't work because time property does not exists anymore.
to solve it just add time property in your group pipeline.

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        $group: 
            {
                _id: 
                    {
                        'bank': '$bank', 
                        'time': '$time'
                    }, 
                sum: 
                    {
                        $sum: '$amount'
                    }
            }
    },
    {
        $group: 
            {
                _id: '$_id.bank', 

// Adding time property.

                time: { $first: '$_id.time'},

                data: {'$push': '$$ROOT'}, 
                sum: {$sum: '$sum'}
            }
    }, {$sort: {time:-1}} 
]).pretty()
```